# fgets from stdin with unpredictable input size

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I'm trying to read a line from `stdin` but I don't know to properly handle the cases when input size is at least equal to the limit. Example code:

```
void myfun() {
    char buf[5];
    char somethingElse;

    printf("\nInsert string (max 4 characters): ");
    fgets (buf, 5, stdin);

    ...

    printf("\nInsert char: ");
    somethingElse = getchar();
}
```

Now, the user can do three things:

1. **Input less than 4 characters** (plus newline): in this case there's nothing left in stdin and the subsequent `getchar()` correctly waits for user input;
2. **Input exactly 4 characters** (plus newline): in this case there's a newline left in stdin and the subsequent `getchar()` reads it;
3. **Input more than 4 characters** (plus newline): in this case there's at least another character left in stdin and the subsequent `getchar()` reads it, leaving at least a newline in.

Cases **2** and **3** would require emptying `stdin` using something like `while(getchar() != '\n')`, whereas case **1** doesn't require any additional action. As I understand from reading answers to similar questions and c-faq, there's no standard/portable way to know whether the actual scenario is the one described in **1** or not.

Did I get it well? Or there actually *is* a portable way to do it? Or maybe a totally different approach?

Comment: Check to see if `buf[]` contains a newline?

Comment: It's maximum 3 chars, not 4, because the `\n` goes also into the buffer.

Comment: You're right @MichaelWalz, the user should be warned about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fgets` function will store the newline in the buffer if there is room for it.  So if the last character in the string is not a newline, you know you need to flush the buffer.

```
fgets (buf, 5, stdin);
if (strrchr(buf, '\n') == NULL) {
    // flush buffer
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF));
}
```

Comment: That's actually so simple, I feel ashamed that I haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

If ones assumes that a *null character* `'\0'` is never read, then [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47718849/2410359) answer will work.

If a *null character* is read, then `strrchr(buf, '\n')` does not find any  `'\n'` that may have been read.

Code could pre-set the buffer to see if a `'\n'` was read in the end.

```
buf[sizeof buf - 2] = '\n';
if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  if (strrchr(buf, '\n') == NULL) {
    // incomplete line read.  (the usual detection)
  } else if (buf[sizeof buf - 2] != '\n') {
    // incomplete line read with prior null character  (see below note).
  }
}
```

Yet the C standard does not specify that data past what was read in `buf[]` is unchanged, pre-filling the buffer with some pattern is not sufficient to detect if a *null character* `'\0'` was read.

> is a portable way to do it?

The most portable way is to use repeated calls to `fgetc()` or the like instead of `fgets()`.

> maybe a totally different approach?

I recommend `fgetc()` or the common but not C standard `getline()`

---

Another alternative: Use `scanf("%4[^\n]%n", buf, &n)`:  It is *very cumbersome*, yet a portable way is possible.  It keeps track of the number of characters read before the `'\n'` even if some are *null characters*.

```
  int n = 0;
  cnt = scanf("%4[^\n]%n", buf, &n);  // Cumbersome to get that 4 here.
  // Lots of TBD code now needed:
  // Handle if cnt != 1 (\n to be read or EOF condition)
  // Handle if n == sizeof buf - 1, (0 or more to read)
  // Handle if n < sizeof buf - 1, (done, now get \n)
  // A \n may still need to be consumed
  // Handle EOF conditions
```

Comment: I discarded the "repeated `fgetch()` option, but I din't think about null characters being input by user. It's not that likely to happen, but you're never too safe, I guess. The fact that the C standard does not guarantee data after the `\0` to stay unchanged, actually brings the `fgetc()` option back to life. Good answer!

Comment: @pimple "It's not that likely to happen." I agree - unless that user is  a hacker.  Much of (early) C is predicated on a trusted user.  That model is risky going forward.  Code as needed.